# Can you steal ball in a maul?

Tags: rugby-union, rugby

Can you steal a ball during a maul? If so what happens after a defensive player steals it?

Answer (score 3):

> Can you steal a ball during a maul?

There's [nothing in the rule book](https://www.world.rugby/the-game/laws/law/16) that forbids it.

> The purpose of a maul is to allow players to compete for the ball, which is held off the ground.

You challenge the opponent(s) and compete for the ball. As long as he doesn't break any of the rules, *a player ripping the ball from the ball carrier must stay in contact with that player until they have transferred the ball.*

> If so what happens after a defensive player steals it?

The ball switches sides, but the players can still compete for the ball according to the rules. You can still [win the ball back](https://www.rugbycoachweekly.net/rugby-drills-and-skills/rucking-mauling/winning-back-maul-ball) with enough training, efforts and strenght.